# pig single group by value per reducer

Tags: apache-pig, grouping, distinct, skew

I have a pig script which does grouping and count distinct customers as below

```
    by_customer = GROUP customer BY (start_date, spc);
     cust_cnt = FOREACH by_customer {
     cust =     DISTINCT customer.cid;
     GENERATE  FLATTEN(group), COUNT(cust);
    };
```

The issue is that the last reducer hangs or fails due to memory issues.
I can see that the data distributed among the reducers is highly skewed.
Is there a way to distribute the output of group by such that each reducer gets only one grouped bag.

Comment: Have you tried using PARALLEL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by doing a workaround to get distinct count without using distinct keyword.

`by_customer = GROUP customer BY (cid,start_date,spc);
dist_customer = FOREACH by_customer GENERATE group.start_date as start_date,group.spc as spc,1 as cst_cnt;
cust = GROUP dist_customer by (start_date,spc);
cust_cnt = FOREACH cust  GENERATE FLATTEN(group), SUM(dist_customer.cst_cnt);`

This worked perfectly.
Not sure why distinct does not work.

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parallel statement for the group by to increase the amount of reducers. If your data is really, really skewed this won't help though since one reducer still might get too much data. The ususal way of alleviating this is by introducing a random number field and adding that to the group by.

```
customer_random = foreach customer generate RANDOM() as seed, start_date, spc, cid, ...
by_customer = group customer_random by (seed, start_date, spc);
```

Obviously this generates different groups than originally so you need to take that into account when further processing (different counts, sums, etc.). Makes things a bit more complicated, but should distribute data better between reducers.